# NVIDIA drivers in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary-drivers

I have an ASUS K501LB
[specs](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K501LB/specifications/)

I am running Fedora 25 with GNOME on Wayland. (right?  That's the default now I think).  Installed 1 week ago.

Following the instructions here [RPMFusion/HOWTO/NVIDIA](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA?action=show&redirect=Howto%2FnVidia)

But when I try to determine my card model with

```
/sbin/lspci | grep -e VGA
```

the only output I get is

```
$ /sbin/lspci | grep -e VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

This system, per the specs and the case stickers, has a GeForce 940M

Is there another way to confirm this?  Do I proceed based on the unconfirmed information?  Is it normal or unusual for nothing about the NVIDIA card to be returned?  thx

Comment: Have you tried `$ lspci | grep NVIDIA`?